# Wrapping directive with HTML

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I was hoping this would be much more straight forward, but I'm stuck. I'm trying to figure out how I can wrap a select with HTML without disrupting the select itself.

As far as I can see, if I make a directive called 'select', it'll trigger when I add a select to my HTML. And unless I don't understand it correctly, transclusion is the right means of doing this.

So I setup a simple enough directive just to add HTML around the select, but it doesn't do anything. If I add both `transclude: true` and `replace: true`, it sorta works, though it takes the attributes of the select and moves it to my the template div.

I figured a plnkr is the easiest way to share this code. Should I type it out here too? http://plnkr.co/edit/MhADL7dKFRV7neCHPxeP?p=preview

Comment: did you try putting a select within the div and putting the ng-transclude attribute on that?

Comment: No, though that's what I was going to do next. I figured that would work, but I wanted to see if I could do it in the simplest way first.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to write template HTML and just want to adjust DOM around select element, one of most simple way to wrap directive is something like this.

```
.directive('select', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(scope, element){
            // adjust element as you want
            //element.addClass('prettySelect');
            element.wrap('<div class="prettySelect"></div>');
        }
    }
});
```

[jsfiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/7xL9zt1w/1/)

Comment: I need to wrap it in a div. The idea is to convert the select to a HTML/JS driven select box so I can style it as I want. Just adding a class doesn't help.

Comment: You can also wrap it in a div. I edit my answer and [jsfiddle updated is here](https://jsfiddle.net/yazaki/7xL9zt1w/2/).